# Joining multiple Database on same server SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to query from two databases - located on the same server.  The first database query is a bit complex with a JOIN and UNION clauses, but joining to the other database is pretty straight forward.  I keep getting an error on the last line of code - `SITE_ID_NUMBER`.

I have never attempted this - any clues as to what I may be doing wrong? Additional note - the JOIN clause for the databases is made of of one native column - i.e. "6041" and one calculated - I had to use a `SUBSTRING` and add the 6 to get the matching value.

Update - After a few changes I am actually getting the error:

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
>   The column 'RECORD_DATE_TIME' was specified multiple times for 'P'.

Thank you.

```
SELECT P.[6] + SUBSTRING(A.SHIP_TO,6,3) AS 'STORE' ,
       S.SITE_ID_NUMBER,
       S.DM,
       S.AREA,
       S.STORE_NAME,
       S.LOCATION,
       P.WHSE AS 'DIVISION_DESC', 
       P.ORDER_STATUS,
       P.MATERIAL,
       P.DESCRIPTION,
       P.PO_NUMBER AS 'CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER',
       P.ORDER_QUANTITY AS'QTY',
       P.RSHIP_DATE AS 'REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE',
       S.TRANSIT_6040_6041

FROM

(SELECT *

FROM  PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_ADIDAS_RETAIL_aRI A
JOIN  PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_WB_DELIVERIES D
ON    A.DELIVERY_NUMBER = D.DELIVERY_NUMBER

UNION ALL 

SELECT *

FROM   PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_ADIDAS_RETAIL_aRO A
JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_WB_DELIVERIES D
ON     A.DELIVERY_NUMBER = D.DELIVERY_NUMBER) P 

JOIN [ADI_USER.MAINTAINED].dbo.SiteDataAdiRbk S

ON  S.SITE_ID_NUMBER = P.STORE;
```

Comment: You actually have a column named "6"?

Comment: _Never_ use `SELECT *` as it causes these confusing errors. Always specifically list columns, especially when using a `UNION`. If you specifically list your columns, you'll probably find your issue. The problem is probably in your last query. I suggest you do some more detailed troubleshooting by running bits and pieces of  your query, then post back something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 32 The column 'RECORD_DATE_TIME' was specified multiple times for 'P'.` RECORD_DATE_TIME is nowhere in the query you gave. Anyway, the error is clear. I'll show you a simple example which reproduces your error. Use this example to fix your code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Join the table to itself as shown to get this error.

```
select *
from
(
select *
from t1 inner join t1 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
) as t

Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 't'.
```

Answer (score 1):

At the outermost level you have 2 table aliases accessible:

- P : Which is the result set from the sub query with the Union
- S : Which is an alias for the table [ADI_USER.MAINTAINED].dbo.SiteDataAdiRbk

The very first item in your select list is *P.[6] + SUBSTRING(**A**.SHIP_TO,6,3) AS 'STORE'*

You are referencing a table or alias named A, which is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the replies and good ideas.  After some much needed focus on other projects, the answer came to me all of the sudden and it appears to be working so far.  I wouldn't have gotten there with out the injection of ideas though. My goal was to join a table created in our workplaces user maintained folder where I have read/write to a database that pulls delivery info and by doing it as I have below that is working - I will say I need to dig further to account for variations on where shipments are coming from as there is two possible locations but this is much much better than we have now and even new analysts will be able to run and post to the report site.

```
SELECT AD.STORE,
       S.DM,
       S.AREA,
       S.STORE_NAME,
       S.LOCATION,
       AD.DIVISION_DESC, 
       AD.ORDER_STATUS,
       AD.MATERIAL,
       AD.DESCRIPTION,
       AD.CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER,
       AD.QTY,
       AD.REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE,
       S.TRANSIT_6040_6041,
       AD.REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE + S.TRANSIT_6040_6041 AS'ESTIMATED_ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE'


FROM 

(

SELECT '6' + SUBSTRING(A.SHIP_TO,6,3) AS 'STORE',
       '' AS 'DM',
       '' AS 'AREA',
       '' AS 'STORE_NAME',
       '' AS 'LOCATION',
       A.WHSE AS 'DIVISION_DESC', 
       A.ORDER_STATUS,
       D.MATERIAL,
       D.DESCRIPTION,
       A.PO_NUMBER AS 'CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER',
       D.ORDER_QUANTITY AS'QTY',
       A.RSHIP_DATE AS 'REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE',
       '' AS 'TRANSIT',
       '' AS 'ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE'


FROM  VW_ADIDAS_RETAIL_aRI A
JOIN  VW_WB_DELIVERIES D
ON    A.DELIVERY_NUMBER = D.DELIVERY_NUMBER

GROUP BY A.SHIP_TO,
       A.WHSE,
       A.ORDER_STATUS,
       A.PO_NUMBER,
       D.MATERIAL, 
       D.DESCRIPTION, 
       D.ORDER_QUANTITY,
       A.RSHIP_DATE,
       A.ASHIP_DATE

HAVING A.ORDER_STATUS NOT IN ('shp')

UNION ALL 

SELECT '6' + SUBSTRING(A.SHIP_TO,6,3) AS 'STORE',
       '' AS 'DM',
       '' AS 'AREA',
       '' AS 'STORE_NAME',
       '' AS 'LOCATION',
       A.WHSE AS 'DIVISION_DESC',
       A.ORDER_STATUS,
       D.MATERIAL,
       D.DESCRIPTION,
       A.PO_NUMBER AS 'CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER',
       D.ORDER_QUANTITY AS'QTY',
       A.RSHIP_DATE AS 'REQUESTED_SHIP_DATE',
       '' AS 'TRANSIT',
       '' AS 'ESTIMATED_DELIVERY_DATE'

FROM   VW_ADIDAS_RETAIL_aRO A
JOIN   VW_WB_DELIVERIES D
ON     A.DELIVERY_NUMBER = D.DELIVERY_NUMBER

GROUP BY A.SHIP_TO,
       A.WHSE,
       A.ORDER_STATUS,
       A.PO_NUMBER,
       D.MATERIAL, 
       D.DESCRIPTION, 
       D.ORDER_QUANTITY,
       A.RSHIP_DATE,
       A.ASHIP_DATE

HAVING A.ORDER_STATUS NOT IN ('shp')) AD

JOIN [ADI_USER_MAINTAINED].dbo.SiteDataAdiRbk S 

ON AD.STORE = S.SITE_ID_NUMBER;
```